# Velocity, how to retrieve a hashmap value using another velocity variable

Tags: velocity

I have a HashMap in my bean:

```
HashMap<String, SomeObject> someHashMap;
```

Then in the velocity template I need to access the HashMap with a value that I have in velocity from other source (in fact I have many keys not only one that's why I need to get the values this way):

```
$key
```

How can I access the hashmap with this key? I'm trying:

```
$someHashMap.get($key)
```

and

```
${someHashMap.get($key)}
```

But those two only write the same thing to the output, meaning that with the first line I literally get:

```
$someHashMap.get($key)
```

In the webpage.

Which is the correct way/syntaxis to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct syntax, and they should work.

- Does `$key` have the right value? Print it.
- Does `$someHashMap` indeed point to the map? Print it. If not, perhaps you forgot to put in the `VelocityContext` being used.
- Is the value stored under that key `null`? The default behavior of Velocity is to print out the code that was called when the outcome is `null`. To make it not do that, use the silent notation: `$!{someHashMap.get($key)}`

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. In my case I tried to do this:

```
$map.get($locale)
```

where `$locale` is e.g. `"fi_FI"`. I solved it by adding quotes inside the brackets:

```
$map.get("$locale")
```

I'm not sure, but I think the rationale goes like this:

```
$map.get( $locale ) -> $map.get( fi_FI ) -> Velocity gets confused

$map.get("$locale") -> $map.get("fi_FI") -> Velocity retrieves correct value
```