# Velocity template - retrieving hashmap values

Tags: velocity

I have a HashMap< String, List> which I fill inside the Java class. When I try to print it out in the Velocity template, it looks fine.

```
$!valuesMap ##gives {33=[texxxxt], 34=[2019-03-31], 35=[admin], 37=[P1], 40=[value1, value2]}
```

When I try to access the values directly, it also looks fine.

```
$!valuesMap.get("40") ##gives [value1, value2]
```

Problem arises when I try to use a dynamic variable to access the map. I have a list of objects over which I iterate, and each of these objects has an ID. However I cant figure out how to retrieve the value from the map using this ID.

```
#foreach( $field in $fields )
    $!field.ID ##gives the id of the object, i.e. 40

    ##I would assume this would give me [value1, value2] when ID is 40, but it returns nothing
    $!valuesMap.get($!field.ID) 
#end
```

I have tried assigning the ID to a new variable (variable itself prints out fine, but again when I try to access the map, I get nothing). I have tried the notation suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541264/velocity-how-to-retrieve-a-hashmap-value-using-another-velocity-variable) and nothing ever prints out, it is honestly driving me up the wall, because I am probably missing something very simple, but cant figure out what it is.

Comment: try adding double quotes as `$!valuesMap.get("$!field.ID")`

Answer (score 0):

Velocity Engine 1.7 does not convert method arguments towards expected types. So if `$field.ID` is a number, you have to enclose it in double quotes to get a string:

```
$valuesMap.get("$field.ID")
```

Otherwise, the engine simply doesn't find a proper method to call.

Starting with 2.0, Velocity Engine will automatically convert method arguments towards expected types, and your code will work as expected.